# BLE Notification freezes all other activities read characteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

After the Notification is enabled from the

```
 BluetoothGatt gatt= leBluetoothService.getmBluetoothGatt();
        gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(chracteristicId, enable);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = chracteristicId.getDescriptor(
                UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

I couldn't read data from any other characteristic. It freezes all the characteristics. why is it so? and after the Notification is enabled it doesn't read data from that characteristic too.

**Edit:**

after the set notification is called all the read and notification starts stacking up instead of performing it. I have used a synchronized static method for each operation.

```
  public static void AddOperation(Operation opr) {
        operations.add(opr) ;
        Log.d("operations",String.valueOf(operations.size()));
        if (currentOperation ==null){
            currentOperation = opr;

            request(opr);


        }
    }

    private static synchronized void request(Operation operation) {
        Log.d("kala", ""+operation);
        operation.execute();


    }
    public static synchronized void operationCompleted() {
        currentOperation = null;
        if (operations.peek() != null) {
            currentOperation = operations.poll();
            Log.d("kalaa", ""+currentOperation);
            currentOperation.execute();
        }

    }
```

all of the read operations perform well but if the characteristic has notified property the operations start stacking up. is there any method to see when the notification is set?

Comment: Are you overriding the [`onDescriptorWrite`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onDescriptorWrite(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor,%20int)) callback method and calling `operationCompleted` there? If not, your queue of operations will get stuck because you aren't telling it when it's safe to move on to the next operation!

Comment: well in the current situation I am not writing to the descriptor because of the different Client Characteristic UUID but somehow it works. thanks @stkent

Comment: I see `gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);` in your posted code so it _does_ look like your are writing to a descriptor; if that is indeed the case, the solution is hopefully less mysterious!